# Java RESTEasy WebService - Download the image file from HTTPResponse object.

Tags: web-services

I need to download a image files from the file system using RESTEasy web service and the input httpclient is JSON and the output response is
  `@Produces({"image/jpeg,image/png"})`

Here is my client code:

```
public void getFileDownload(){  
        log("inside getServerPath....");
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(downloadWebService_URL);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("filePath", "/ngs/app/sample.png");
        json.put("fileName", "sample.png");

        log("json-->"+json.toString());

        StringEntity inputJson = null;
        try {
            inputJson = new StringEntity(json.toString());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        log("inputJson = " + inputJson.toString());

        inputJson.setContentType("application/json");
        httpPost.setEntity(inputJson);
        httpPost.addHeader("AppType", "TC");

        log("httpPost... httpPost");
        HttpResponse response = null; 
        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            log("response:-->"+response);
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            log("E:: " + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        }
    }
```

Here is my Webservice code:

```
@Path("/downloadservice")
public class DownloadFileWS {

  private static final String FILE_PATH = "/ngs/app/sample.png";

    @POST  
   // @Path("/images") 
    @Path("/{fileName}/images")
    @Consumes({"application/json"}) 
    @Produces({"image/jpeg,image/png"})
    public Response getImageFile(@PathParam("fileName") String fileName) {  
        File file = new File(FILE_PATH);    
        System.out.println("File requested is : " + fileName);
        Logger.getLogger("!!!!!!!!!!!"+FILE_PATH);
        System.out.println("@@@@@@@@"+FILE_PATH);
        ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);  
        response.header("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"sample.png\""); 
        return response.build();  
    }
```

The HTTP Response is:

> response:-->HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Date: Tue, 19 Jul 2016 00:36:22 GMT,
>   Content-Length: 6192, Content-Type: image/png, Content-Disposition:
>   attachment; filename="sample.png", X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1]
>   org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity@2ace1307

Question:
1. Based on the response, it looks like the service is sending the image in HTTPResponse object. May i know how to download the image received from HTTP Response? 
2. The requirement is to click a link which calls the webservice by passing JSON as input request and the image should automatically download to the user's local machine browser.

Comment: Can someone please let me know how to download the HttpResponse as a file in clients/users browser during Resteasy web service call?